# node.js mssql UPDATE Statements take > 1 minute to execute

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, pooling, node-mssql

At the moment I am deploying a node.js application with IIS reverse proxy at a test server. I am working with mssql package to connect to the SQL Server 2014. For testing on my local machine everything worked fine (SQL Server 2019), but now on the test server I mentioned a really strange behaviour of `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements on the server.

Example statement:

```
UPDATE name 
FROM renters 
WHERE id = 1
```

Very trivial statements like this, in rather small tables (< 400 rows, < 200 columns) sometimes take 1-2 minutes to execute, while `SELECT` statements execute immediately without delay.

Up to now I could not identify a reasonable problem that causes this behaviour. I was thinking about maybe it is about the SQL Server version or about some restrictions only on `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements by the Database manager, but in my eyes that's also not really realistic, or maybe due to a strange behaviour of the pooling connections? Am I missing something?

BTW I am using the basic connnector, proposed by mssql with pool connections like this:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const sqlConfig = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PWD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  server: 'localhost',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  }
}

async () => {
 try {
  // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
  await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
  const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
  console.dir(result)
 } catch (err) {
  // ... error checks
 }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it's an injection security concern.

Comment: @Larnu ... but I don't get why it is not blocked then, but just delayed.

Comment: Are there any update trigger(s) on the table? Poorly implemented triggers, especially ones that access external dependencies like web services, are often a source of performance issues. Triggers should be as simple and efficient as possible.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Correction to the upper description: I could observe the same behaviour also for INSERT statements. 

As far as I know there are no triggers on the table. I have to add that the behaviour is true for all tables of the database, not just one.

Comment: What happens when you execute that same statement from SSMS, instead of through Node?